# Will a Nikon AF-S Nikkor 50mm 1: 1.8 G lens work on my Nikon D3100 series camera?

Tags: compatibility

Will an AF-S Nikkor 50mm 1:1.8G work well with my with Nikon D3100?

Comment: Good evening Michael and welcome to Photo.SE! Please take a moment to take [the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) On this Q&A website it's expected of question askers that they describe what they've tried so far to solve their own question and also to provide details on their question. It's ok if your research did not give you answers, but then at least we know what you've looked at so far and what else we can tell you. Have you checked Nikon's website to see if the lens will fit on your camera? If so, what did you find? What does "working well" mean for you?

Comment: You can [edit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/121209/edit) your question if you would like to add new information.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to Photo-SE. To help make your question better, let me ask you, do you have reason to think it won't work? Are you considering purchasing the lens? Also, when editing your question, please edit the title to be descriptive and specific to your question. "Compatibility of lenses" could apply to thousands of questions. For instance, most of them probably have nothing to do with Nikon cameras or lenses. When writing titles to questions, aim for complete sentences ending in a question mark. See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/175991).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Nikon AF-S "G" lenses autofocus on D3xxx bodies?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/90086)

Comment: To understand what the letters on the lens mean, see the Nikon Lenses answer to: [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183)

Comment: Good Day All. Firstly I am new to all this and at an age were progress can easily baffle me. I really do appreciate all of your comments and suggestions of making good titles to questions and related sites that will be of help. I don't even know if I am writing this in the correct place. Anyhow. Yes I am thinking of purchasing this lens. I have only just gone to digital and found it really fascinating. My boy is a freelance and his advice was to try and find the lens as it is much better than the 3.5 which comes with the standard box. If I am doing anything wrong on this site tell me. Michael

Answer (score 2):

AF-S Nikkor 50mm 1.8G will work fine on D3100 as all G lenses will. G (gelded) lenses have built in focusing motor and don't need camera screw driver motor to focus them, which is not present on Nikon 3xxx and 5xxx series.

Comment: Hi George and thank you. So the lens will auto focus without any problems?Michael

Comment: Yes, It will :)